# How to search for photos taken with a certain camera model in Wikimedia Commons?

Tags: wikimedia-commons

How to search for all the photos taken with a certain camera model in Wikimedia Commons?

For example I want to search for the photos taken with DSC-WX70. Only a small part of such files are included in the [Category:Taken with Sony DSC-WX70](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Taken_with_Sony_DSC-WX70)

The Metadata of the files is not included in the Wikimedia Commons backup, so I can't use AWB database scanner.

Is there any way to search for such files - other than typing "DSC-WX70 site:commons.wikimedia.org" in Google - in a manner that can create a list with all such files?